# How to set divider between columns in tablelayout?

Tags: android, divider, android-tablelayout

I want to create a table with column dividers. I want to divide my columns with a vertical bar image. To achieve this I have used `"android:divider="@drawable/abc"`  but its not working. Below is my xml file for same:

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:padding="5dip"
android:divider="@drawable/tracking_green"
>
<TableRow  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/retaileritem1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="xxxxxxx" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/retaileritem2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="xxxxxxx" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/retailerimage1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/tracking_green" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 14):

Add android:showDividers="middle"

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:padding="5dip"
  android:divider="@drawable/tracking_green"
  android:showDividers="middle"
>
```

Comment: is there any way to change color of the divider as well.?

Comment: For example:
If you use --- android:divider="@color/orangeBackground"
Then you can define value at colors.xml like --- <color name="orangeBackground">#FF8000</color>

Answer (score 5):

It's quite late to answer this question but here is the correct way to it.

For dividers between rows :

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:showDividers="middle">
```

and for dividers between columns:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:showDividers="middle">
```

Explaination:

The divider tag in `<TableLayout>` is used to place divider between it's direct childrens i.e **Rows**.

While the divider tag in `<TableRow>` is used to place divider between it's direct childrens i.e **Columns**

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it !

***CODE***

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    android:text="Salary Details"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:shrinkColumns="0"
                    android:stretchColumns="1" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="Financial Year"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spnSearchByCity"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:entries="@array/year"
                            tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#d30059"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/white" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Month"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Net Salary"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Click"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/white" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Jan"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="11305"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailsOneId"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="#000000"
                                    android:text="DETAILS"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/white" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Feb"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="11405"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="#d30059"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailsTwoId"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="#000000"
                                    android:text="DETAILS"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="50dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMainMenuId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="MAIN MENU"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

---

***Snapshot***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What i wanted is a table like this

[image: table image with vertical dividers]

I added this in my styles.xml

```
    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Divider_invisible">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    </style>

Then in my table layout 

 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#92C94A" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider_invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/main_wo_colon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/side_wo_colon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#6F9C33" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/servings"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <View style="@style/Divider" />
                </LinearLayout>

..........
.......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

since tablelayout does not provide this directly, one posibble way might be a framelayout. place the desired table above another background_table wich only have one row and "match_parent" for height/width. add 3 columns with desired layout_weights. add vertical divider-imageview to second column.
the main table should also use the same layout_weihts +margin in it`s rows to look good.

horizontal divider possibly could be realized by adding an imageview between the "to-be-separated" tablerows.

not tested yet, just an approach

ornay

Answer (score 0):

In a list with a vertical divider use the ImageView as follows:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:contentDescription="@string/divider"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp" 
    android:background="#3B3B3B"
    />
```

To avoid showing a divider when there aren't elements in the list you can delete the `android:background="#3B3B3B"` line and set it programmatically:

```
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.divider)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3B3B3B"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try set the second textview marginleft=1dp. if you don't want divider set marginleft = 0dp