# How to add a drawable line in between, dividing it into two column

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

Below is the xml file that I have written. I am getting a border in the outer side and in between two rows. I don't know how to get the border dividing a row into two columns, like dividing the two text view in between.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:backgroundTint="#111"
android:fadeScrollbars="true">
<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:divider="#111"
  android:showDividers="middle"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"

  >
  <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_margin="2dip"

      >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/TeamAB"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#111"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/teamBA"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#111"
    />
  </TableRow>
<TableRow
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/scoreAB"
    android:textColor="#111"
  android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/scoreBA"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"

    android:textColor="#111"
    />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

cell_shape.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle"  >
 <solid android:color="#0fff"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp"  android:color="#000"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

Tried with android:divider and android:show dividers, it isn't working.

Edit- Any changes will be appreciated too in the code, to get desired result!

Comment: Try this link [formatted table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073211/how-to-set-divider-between-columns-in-tablelayout). may be it will helpfull to you

Comment: @SharadGautam tried that similar code, that ain't working

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="Column one " />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="column two"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: it will show example of add divider in between two views. modify it according to your need

Comment: hmm tried adding <View> in  my layout  between textview as you said. changes the whole layout. try doing that in my xml file.