# How to set separators for rows in table layout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tablelayout, separator

I am very new to xamarin.andriod, I am trying to design a table with many rows. Everything is fine but I am not able to get a separator properly for rows.
Here is my code:

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="50px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"            
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow               
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            android:id="@+id/tableHeader1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxEms="3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="!"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/rowNotFilledIndication"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:tag="RowIncomplete" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username4"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:id="@+id/username3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

And here is the output I am getting

[image]

But I just want a ending line for each row completion instead of two lines for the row.
Is there any way to get only one line after the row completion?

Comment: Please look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073211/how-to-set-divider-between-columns-in-tablelayout

Comment: Thank you @JonasE. I tried them but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a view, make sure you set your show:divider to none

```
          <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
```

Comment: Thank you for the responce @KARAM JABER, should it be placed after the table row?

Comment: If you want to display separator in table row, you can do this, please take a look this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/table-layout